Guess the number game with an easy and hard mode
I have started learning to program in Python. I watched a YouTube course for beginners creating the well known "guess the number" game. I have attempted to write an improved version of the game.
How can may code be improved?
import random
from colorama import Fore


def is_number(technical_number):
    if int(technical_number) == 1:
        global range_min
        while range_min.isdigit() is False and int(range_min.count('-')) == 0 or float(range_min) % 1 != 0:
            print(Fore.RED)
            print('Введите целое число!')

            print(Fore.BLUE)
            range_min = input("Введите наименьшее число в диапозоне: ")
            range_min = range_min.strip()
    elif int(technical_number) == 2:
        global range_max
        while range_max.isdigit() is False and int(range_max.count('-')) == 0 or float(range_max) % 1 != 0:
            print(Fore.RED)
            print('Введите целое число!')

            print(Fore.BLUE)
            range_max = input("Введите наибольшее число в диапозоне: ")
            range_max = range_max.strip()
    else:
        global user_number
        global text
        while user_number.isdigit() is False and int(user_number.count('-')) == 0 or float(user_number) % 1 != 0:
            print(Fore.RED)
            print('Введите целое число!')

            print(Fore.CYAN)
            user_number = input(text)
            user_number = user_number.strip()


def is_number_repetition():
    global repetition
    while repetition.isdigit() is False or repetition == ():
        print(Fore.RED)
        print('Введите натуральное число или ноль!')

        print(Fore.MAGENTA)
        repetition = input('Сколько раз вы хотите запустить игру? ')
        repetition = repetition.strip()


def more():
    global range_min, range_max
    while int(range_min) > int(range_max):
        print(Fore.RED)
        print(f"Введите число большее или равное {range_min}!")

        print(Fore.BLUE)
        range_max = input("Введите большее число в диапозоне: ")
        range_max = range_max.strip()
        is_number(2)


def more_user():
    global user_number
    while int(user_number) > int(range_max) or int(user_number) < int(range_min):
        print(Fore.RED)
        print(f"Введите число от {range_min} до {range_max}!")

        print(Fore.CYAN)
        user_number = input(f"Угадайте число от {range_min} до {range_max}: ")
        user_number = user_number.strip()


print(Fore.YELLOW)
print('Игра "Угадай число"')
print("В этой игре вы пытаетесь угадать число, загаданное рандомайзером в выбранном вами диапозоне")

print(Fore.RESET)
mode = input("Какой режим вы хотите выбрать? Обычный или лёгкий (с подсказками)? ")
mode = mode.strip()
mode_easy = ["Лёгкий", "С подсказками", "Лёгкий с подсказками", "Лёгкий (с подсказками)", "лёгкий", "с подсказками",
             "лёгкий с подсказками", "лёгкий (с подсказками)", "л", "ЛЁГКИЙ", "С ПОДСКАЗКАМИ", "ЛЁГКИЙ С ПОДСКАЗКАМИ",
             "ЛЁГКИЙ (С ПОДСКАЗКАМИ)", "ЛЁГКИЙ", "С ПОДСКАЗКАМИ", "ЛЁГКИЙ (С ПОДСКАЗКАМИ)", "Л"]
mode_normal = ["Обычный", "обычный", "о", "ОБЫЧНЫЙ", "ОБЫЧНЫЙ", "О"]
mode_sum = [mode_easy, mode_normal]
mode_sum = sum(mode_sum, [])

while mode not in mode_sum:
    print(Fore.RED)
    print("Выберите один из предложенных режимов!")

    print(Fore.RESET)
    mode = input("Какой режим вы хотите выбрать? Обычный или лёгкий (с подсказками)? ")
    mode = mode.strip()

if mode in mode_normal:
    print(Fore.YELLOW)
    print('Обычный режим')
    print("В нём вы пытаетесь угадать число, загаданное рандомайзером в выбранном ваме диапозоне, но без подсказок")

    print(Fore.MAGENTA)
    repetition = input("Сколько раз вы хотите сыграть в игру? ")
    repetition = repetition.strip()
    is_number_repetition()

    victory_counter = 0
    defeat_counter = 0

    for game in range(int(repetition)):
        print(Fore.BLUE)
        range_min = input("Введите наименьшее число в диапозоне: ")
        range_min = range_min.strip()
        is_number(1)

        range_max = input("Введите наибольшее число в диапозоне: ")
        range_max = range_max.strip()
        is_number(2)

        more()

        print(Fore.CYAN)
        print(f"Ваш диапозон: от {range_min} до {range_max}")

        random_number = random.randint(int(range_min), int(range_max))
        text = f"Угадайте число от {range_min} до {range_max}: "
        user_number = input(text)
        user_number = user_number.strip()
        is_number(3)

        more_user()
        is_number(3)

        if int(user_number) == int(random_number):
            print(Fore.GREEN)
            print("Вы угадали число!")
            victory_counter += 1
        else:
            print(Fore.RED)
            print("Вы не угадали число!")
            print(f"Было загадано число {random_number}")
            defeat_counter += 1

    if int(repetition) > 1:
        print(Fore.MAGENTA)
        print("Результаты:")
        print(f"Вы угадали чисел - {victory_counter}")
        print(f"Вы не угадали чисел - {defeat_counter}")

elif mode in mode_easy:
    print(Fore.YELLOW)
    print('Лёгкий режим')
    print("В нём вы пытаетесь угадать число, загаданное рандомайзером в выбранном ваме диапозоне,")
    print("однако вам будут давать подсказки: меньше ваше число, чем загаданное, или больше")

    print(Fore.MAGENTA)
    repetition = input("Сколько раз вы хотите сыграть в игру? ")
    repetition = repetition.strip()
    is_number_repetition()

    for game in range(int(repetition)):
        count = 1

        print(Fore.BLUE)
        range_min = input("Выберите меньшее число в диапозоне: ")
        range_min = range_min.strip()
        is_number(1)

        range_max = input("Выберите большее число в диапозоне: ")
        range_max = range_max.strip()
        is_number(2)

        more()

        user_number = int(range_min) - 1
        random_number = random.randint(int(range_min), int(range_max))

        while int(user_number) != random_number:
            print(Fore.CYAN)
            user_number = input(f"Угадайте число от {range_min} до {range_max}: ")
            user_number = user_number.strip()
            is_number(3)

            more_user()

            if int(user_number) > random_number:
                print(Fore.YELLOW)
                print("Ваше число больше загаданного")
                count += 1
                continue
            elif int(user_number) < random_number:
                print(Fore.YELLOW)
                print("Ваше число меньше загаданного")
                count += 1
                continue

        if str(count)[-1] == '1' and int(count) != 11:
            attempt = 'попытку'
        elif str(count)[-1] in ['2', '3', '4'] and str(count) not in ['12', '13', '14']:
            attempt = 'попытки'
        else:
            attempt = 'попыток'

        print(Fore.GREEN)
        print(f"Вы угадали число за {count} {attempt}!!!")

A play through of the game with the output translated into English:


meaningful identifiers
You wrote:
def is_number(technical_number): ...

def is_number_repetition(): ...

def more(): ...

def more_user(): ...

You elected not to write any """docstring""" for these
functions, fine, maybe the identifiers make them self explanatory.
Next week we will hire a new maintenance engineer.
We will assign that person the task of authoring new
unit tests
which exercise these four helpers.
It's unclear whether that person
will view those four identifiers
in the same way that you view them,
with identical semantics.
There is an opportunity to clarify the semantics
before any hiring actions happen next week.
signature
def is_number(technical_number):

You didn't really tell us if we should expect technical_number: float,
or maybe a Decimal or Fraction or perhaps an int.
The """docstring""" gives you an opportunity to describe such details,
or you could choose to take advantage of optional type annotations,
perhaps with def is_number(technical_number: float): -> None:
Which raises the question, why is a bool predicate function is_foo()
defined as void (return None) rather than as some boolean predicate?
This is a
POLA
violation.
When we name a function is_foo(),
there are certain expectations that come along with that,
like returning a bool result.
You can certainly buck convention,
the machine won't mind.
But when you share your expression of technical ideas with colleagues,
they might not see them in the same light that you see them.
defined concept
The notion of a "technical" number seems to be somehow
different from other kinds of numbers, e.g. natural,
rational, real, imaginary, irrational, transcendental....
Google apparently defines the notion as corresponding
to the set of positive integers within
NANPA
where someone will pick up and answer technical support questions.
When introducing a new concept, it is important to
offer a definition or at least cite some author who does so.
In the OP code, I have no idea what the "tech" vs "non-tech"
distinction might be.
coupling
        global range_min

Don't do it.
Just don't even go there.
Module top-level global vars are seldom the right answer.
Prefer to define a class, with certain class invariants,
and then we can talk about self.range_min.
object lifetime
        global range_min
        while range_min.isdigit() is False and ...

Apparently the Author believes the module-level range_min
shall be set by the time that is_number() runs.
There's nothing in the source to help us with this assumption,
for example a ToC self.x = x assignment in an __init__ constructor.
            print('Weka nambari kamili!')

If it was so important to enter a nambari,
it would have been helpful to spell that out
in the function signature's optional type annotations.
            range_min = input("Ingiza nambari ndogo zaidi katika safu: ")

It's unclear what's going on here.
Should the Gentle Reader assume that range_min already
has some value? Or is there a theorem we could prove
that it definitely has some numeric type at this point?
Could numba confidently JIT this function?
global vs self.attribute
        global range_min
        ...
        global range_max
        ...
        global user_number
        global text

This is officially Out Of Control.
Sequester these within a class already.
Global coupling
is a thing, and it isn't pretty.
Choose to design it out of your solutions.
too long
Starting with foreground color yellow and
continuing with if mode in mode_normal: ...,
we see module top-level code which really
should be packaged up within a function,
having some documented
single responsibility.
Actually, packaged using multiple helper functions.
As written, this blob of code is entirely Too Long,
needing vertical scrolling to review all of it,
and we have no {signature, docstring}
to help us reason about what
pre-conditions
it requires and what post-conditions it promises to fulfill.

It is unclear if this code accomplishes most of its design goals.
I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on this codebase in its current form.
